# Using Where() causes System.ArgumentException in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple method, to get all recently modified objects from a `DbSet` in EntityFramework:

```
public List<JobModel> GetJobs()
{
    return db.Jobs
        .Include(j => j.JobStatus)
        .Include(j => j.JobResolution)
        .Include(j => j.Process)
        .Where(j => (DateTime.Now - j.ModifiedDtm).Days < 2)
        .ToList();
}
```

This works fine, without the `.Where(...)` part of the query. But when I add that last bit, I get the following three exceptions:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

All rows in `db.Jobs` has a valid value of `ModifiedDtm` which is prior to `DateTime.Now`. What am I doing wrong? I tried moving the `Where()` method above the `Include()`, but with no luck...

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the @CamiloTerevinto I got a slightly more informative error message. I still don't understand exactly what it means though...

> DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

Comment: "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.dll" is not the actual exception message. Put a try-catch there and get the actual exception

Comment: Are you using EF Core?

Comment: @RuiJarimba `EntityFramework.dll` is obviously not EF Core (which would be `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you're absolutely right

Comment: No, I am using EntityFramework 6.2.0 (non-core).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for the [`DbFunctions.DiffDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffdays.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) function:

```
return db.Jobs
    .Include(j => j.JobStatus)
    .Include(j => j.JobResolution)
    .Include(j => j.Process)
    .Where(j => DbFunctions.DiffDays(j.ModifiedDtm, DateTime.Now) < 2)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `DateTime.Now` within a `Where` clause in Entity Framework. This is because EF queries are translated to a SQL query, and `DateTime.Now` doesn't exist in SQL. You should try to get the day before the query and pass it as a long variable.

Comment: are you sure that we cannot use  DateTime.Now in EF where clause?

Comment: I have tried pre-calculating `DateTime.Now` and store it in a variable. This doesn't change the error message...